# How to create custom sdk with android hidden api

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, hide

i'm trying to use some classes from android's hidden api, but i can't use it in default android studio. So i decide to do some custom and make sdk with hidden apis with this instruction [click](https://hardiannicko.medium.com/create-your-own-android-hidden-apis-fa3cca02d345). I tried to get framework.jar from 3 emulated devices and 1 physical, but in all cases it was about 1kb (api 28).

So the questions: how can i use hidden api in android studio without reflection? Is it possible to make custom sdk with hidden apis in 2023?

Comment: "i'm trying to use some classes from android's hidden api" -- there is no requirement for any given device model to have those classes. They can vary by OS version, and device manufacturers modify the framework all the time.

Comment: @CommonsWare, oh i didn't know about it, but i want to use standard android classes and methods which annotated with "@hide" in android studio. Do u know how can i do this?